# Why are files in .git directory orange in IntelliJ Local History?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I've been doing various things in IntelliJ with Git, and I'm not sure what happened. I was trying to change the project name for some reason (so I refactored the project and changed the folder name), then decided to change it back. After changing the project name, the Local History in IntelliJ showed the .git directory inside a folder named C:\Users\my_name\IdeaProjects\project_name (the path of the project), below the rest of the changed files (I don't have a screenshot from here, but it's similar to the image below). It didn't show this before.

When I went to Local History to revert the change (Git isn't set up now so I'm using the built-in Local History for now, it's complicated), a pop-up asked me if I wanted to clear the read-only status of a bunch of files in the .git directory. I allowed that because I wasn't sure what to do, and it changed the project name back. However, now, in the Local History still displays this below the rest of any changed files:

[image]

Even if I revert to a time with no Git integration and compare it in Local History with another time with no Git integration, this still shows up.

In summary, I tried to change the title and this appeared. I then tried to change it back by reverting using Local History and this is still here. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: You shouldn't be looking in the git folder. And don't say Git isn't set up, that's Git you're looking at.

Comment: Could you please go to Preferences | Editor | File Types -> Ingored Files and Folders and see whether .git is present there? Have you edited this part of settings? What do you see under File | Project structure?